# Weird if statement giving me problems

Tags: java

The problem which I am trying to solve is

> An IP address is a numerical label assigned to each device (e.g.,
>   computer, printer) participating in a computer network that uses the
>   Internet Protocol for communication. There are two versions of the
>   Internet protocol, and thus two versions of addresses. One of them is
>   the IPv4 address.
>
> IPv4 addresses are represented in dot-decimal notation, which consists
>   of four decimal numbers, each ranging from 0 to 255 inclusive,
>   separated by dots, e.g., 172.16.254.1.
>
> Given a string, find out if it satisfies the IPv4 address naming
>   rules.
>
> Example
>
> For inputString = "172.16.254.1", the output should be
>   isIPv4Address(inputString) = true;
>
> For inputString = "172.316.254.1", the output should be
>   isIPv4Address(inputString) = false.
>
> 316 is not in range [0, 255].
>
> For inputString = ".254.255.0", the output should be
>   isIPv4Address(inputString) = false.
>
> There is no first number.
>
> Input/Output
>
> [execution time limit] 3 seconds (java)
>
> [input] string inputString
>
> Guaranteed constraints: 1 ≤ inputString.length ≤ 30.
>
> [output] boolean
>
> true if inputString satisfies the IPv4 address naming rules, false
>   otherwise.

I am really close to solving this problem, but I cannot seem to get past such a strange logic error which java cannot seem to pick up on. Basically I am parsing a string using Integer.parseInt(temp) and checking to see if it is less than or equal to 255. In the instance where it returns false when it shouldn't, temp = 172. I know this because I've debugged my code several times. 
Code:

```
while(inputString.length() > 0){
    if(inputString.lastIndexOf('.') == -1) {
        temp = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length());
        if(Integer.parseInt(temp) <= 255)
            {return false;}
        for(int i = 0; i<temp.length(); i++) {
            if(!Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(i))){
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The while loop is a little longer because it deals with other parts of the IPV4 address, but I only inserted this because I think it is more important in terms of solving my problem. If needed, I can put the whole code.

Comment: You've got a lot of extra, unnecessary code there. You already know that the numbers are digits if you get through `parseInt`, because it would fail if they weren't. Save the results of `parseInt()` into a variable, and you can test its value directly to see if it falls within the appropriate range.

Comment: Do you have to use this formatting? I am working on a simpler solution for you.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading this, but since 172 <= 255, shouldn't it return false according to your code? Maybe that line should return true since it is in the range of 0-255?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Well, my attempt is to use the harder methods to solve problems instead of using options such as regex to get myself to improve my algorithmic solving abilities.

Comment: There is nothing weird with Java "if" statements, but weird is how you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two big problems here:

1. Why returning `false` when `Integer.parseInt(temp) <= 255`? Doesn't a `false` return indicate an error?  An IP number piece <= 255 is exactly a not-error!
2. Your `for` loop, which you obviously intended to check the validity of all the digits, only checks the first digit.  Why? Both cases of your `if` inside the loop return.  Get rid of the `else return true;` case on that `if`.  Although you *do* want to return `false` immediately if you find a bad digit, you also want to keep the loop going as long as you're finding good digits.

Comment: Yep, I realize my silly error now. As for the for loop, it iterates through every digit. So if the character it is iterating through isn't a digit, it returns false.